# GCC: C standard being used

Tags: gcc, standards

Instead of going through a list of of possible standards seeing which doesn't give errors, is there just a simple gcc option I can use (just checked, not likely) or a config file or info file in the system that says?

Comment: can use for what?  Do you have some source that you want to be able to work on 'any' compiler?

Comment: Was just curious if I could do "gcc -info" or if it is said anywhere on the computer what standard is used by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the -std option to control the language standard used. Values of either c89 (which is the same as using -ansi for C code) or c99 are likely what you want, but there are GNU dialects of both, plus others listed in the manpage.

-std=gnu89 is the default for C, which is "GNU dialect of ISO C90 (including some C99 features)." (ISO's 1990 C standard is ANSI's 1989 standard, known as C89.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i'm missing something, but there is the `-std=` option, documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html).